# MPI: Variable does not increase

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to get an intution about how MPI works. Therefore I started with a little example:

```
...
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nthreads);

int message = 2;

if(tid != 0)
{
    MPI_Recv(&rec, 1, MPI_INT, tid-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("Process %i receive %i\n", tid, rec);
}

if(tid != nthreads-1)
{
    message++;
    printf("Process %i sends %i\n", tid, message);
    MPI_Send(&message, 1, MPI_INT, tid+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
...
```

That works fine despite the fact that `message` does seem to increase above 3. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpirun -np N` command starts `N` MPI processes, not one process with `N` threads. In each process you have variable `message` and each process has its own variable set to 2. Next 0th process sends its `message == 3` to 1st process. After it, 1st process sends his own `message == 3` and 2nd catches it...

Answer (score 2):

The MPI ranks aren't threads, they're - well - "ranks", or Processing Elements sometimes, in MPI speak, but processes generally speaking.

That would normally be a minor detail, but here I think it actually reflects the underlying confusion.  If in OpenMP (say) you had the following code

```
int message = 0;

#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(message)
{
   int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
   if (tid != nthreads-1) {
       #pragma omp atomic
       message++;
   }
}
```

then at the end of the parallel section, message would in fact have been incremented `OMP_NUM_THREADS-1` times.

But MPI isn't threading; when you launch your program with `mpiexec` or `mpirun`, n tasks are launched and each runs the exact same program in its own process -- eg, no shared variables.   In particular, each of the tasks will have their own variable `message`, and that variable will be incremented at most one time in the above code snippet, meaning that `message` will always be 2 or 3 at the end of the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that what you want could be achieved by the following code:

```
int message = 2;

if(tid != 0)
{
   MPI_Recv(&message, 1, MPI_INT, tid-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   printf("Process %i receive %i\n", tid, message);
}

if(tid != nthreads-1)
{
   message++;
   printf("Process %i sends %i\n", tid, message);
   MPI_Send(&message, 1, MPI_INT, tid+1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Thus each process (except rank 0) would receive the value from the previous rank, increment it by one and then pass it to the next rank (except the last rank). For example:

- rank 0 sends `2` to rank 1
- rank 1 receives `2` from rank 0, increments it and sends `3` to rank 2
- rank 2 receives `3` from rank 1, increments it and sends `4` to rank 3
- ...
- rank *nthreads*-1 receives `2+nthreads-1` from rank *nthreads*-2